# When are adjacency lists better than sparse matrices?

Tags: graphs, adjacency-matrix, sparse-matrices

I saw several questions discussion the benefits of adjacency lists over matrices to represent a sparse undirected graph. On the other hand, none of them discuss sparse matrix representations such as `scipy`'s `coo` or `csr` formats.

Do adjacency lists still provide benefits in this case?

Definitions of the above:

- Adjacency list: a graph is represented as a dictionary, where each vertex is associated to the list of its neighbors (and the value of the edge): {i: [(neigh_1, val1), (neigh2, val_2)]}. Suppose these lists are linked lists ;
- `coo` format: the graph is represented as a dictionary of edges: (i,j) -> value.
- `csr` format: the matrix is stored row-wise. For each non-zero row, we have 2 arrays: indices[i] and values[i]. Example: indices[i] = [neigh_1, neigh_2], values[i] = [neigh1, neigh2].

Related: [When are adjacency lists or matrices the better choice?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/79322/when-are-adjacency-lists-or-matrices-the-better-choice?rq=1) and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218322/what-is-better-adjacency-lists-or-adjacency-matrices-for-graph-problems-in-c/5419933#5419933

Comment: Not everybody is an expert on `scipy`. Perhaps you could explain what `coo` and `csr` are, as well as what you mean by *adjacency lists*?

Comment: Right, thanks for the feedback. I added details on the data structures.

Comment: The csr format seems equivalent to the adjacency list format.

Comment: Different usages of course! Non of them is `better` than the other one. Each is used in some situations.